# How can I replace edges by gaps?

Tags: modeling

I have a solid door. I want to divide it along the current edges:

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's a non-destructive proposal using [Modifiers](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/index.html#):

[image]

1. Add an [Edge Split](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/edge_split.html) modifier set to angle `0`
2. Add a [Smooth](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/deform/smooth.html) modifier limited to the width axis
3. Add a [Solidify](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/solidify.html) modifier
4. Add a [Bevel](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/bevel.html) modifier

Comment: .. this makes my answer look so _vulgar_ :D

Comment: @RobinBetts But still valuable - if someone doesn't need a non-destructive solution, yours is quick and easy.

Answer (score 9):

A common strategy for creating adjacent planks, bricks, tiles, etc., is to divide regions *before* giving them thickness.

While the door is still a plane:

1. <kbd>V</kbd> Rip the edges between planks
2. Assign a *Solidify* modifier
3. Assign a *Bevel* modifier, by angle

[image]

Comment: @Chris :D.. now the _Mirror_ modifier should come more naturally.. (rip, 'L' select linked under hover, delete faces on one side)

Comment: @RobinBetts Only that for the original design of the post you can't use the _Mirror_ modifier that easy  ;)

Answer (score 7):

The answers of @DredWolf and @RobinBetts are both good solutions if you're creating from a plane, these answers are how you should do it. Nevertheless, here's something additional to that solution. If you already have an extruded object like the one in your screenshot and you maybe want small grooves between those parts to separate them, you can do the following:

1. Select the edges where you want to create grooves.
2. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to bevel those edges so that each edge becomes a doubled edge.
3. Keep the selection of the new face loops, hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> > *Extrude Faces Along Normals*.
4. Scale them inwards to your liking (or outwards for ridges).

[image: bevel edges]

If you want to make real gaps so that there is space between them, you can use this method. It uses LoopTools (*Preferences* > *Add-ons* > *Mesh: LoopTools*).

1. Select edges as before.
2. Bevel as before.
3. Right-click on the object for the context menu. Choose *LoopTools* > *Bridge*. In this case it only deletes the faces, of course you can do it without *LoopTools*. Just hit <kbd>X</kbd> > *Delete* > *Faces*. The advantage of *LoopTools* is, it keeps the edges selected.
4. With the edges still selected after *Bridge* (or select them after deleting faces), now hit <kbd>F</kbd> to fill the open sides.
5. You've separated the door with gaps between the parts.

[image]

Comment: That's a really cunning use of the 'Remove Internal Faces' feature of _LT_ > _Bridge_  which I've previously never bothered with. Now I'm going to have to resist my muscle-memory to work it in :)